# Can I recover an encrypted partition that I quick-formatted in Lubuntu?

Tags: encryption

I had a USB drive encrypted with dmcrypt+LUKS which I forgot the password to.

I later formatted it but as soon as I formatted it I remembered the password.

Is there any way to recover/restore the partition or is it gone?

Comment: You don't.  Its been nuked.

Comment: aw crap. I thought that would be the case but I wanted to check anyway. Oh well.

Comment: Tried mounting/opening it with `cryptsetup` now? Maybe the LUKS header is still there... probably not, but just maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

- A backup of the LUKS header (from `luksHeaderBackup <device> --header-backup-file <file>`)
- The master key (from the option `--dump-master-key` the actual encryption key, no passphrase required)

then it might be possible to recover some files, depending on how much was overwritten.

- With a backup LUKS header, you could use `--header <device or file storing the LUKS header>` with `open` to open the container using the backup header and a passphrase.
- With the master key, you could use `--master-key-file` with `open` to open the LUKS device without a passphrase.

See `man cryptsetup` for more descriptions of the options & usage.

Even if some areas were overwritten, it might be possible to repair/recover some files, either fixing the filesystem or doing an "undelete" type search, or a data carving tool to grab the remaining readable files. [`testdisk`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=testdisk&searchon=sourcenames) can go a long way towards those goals.